# Weird behaviour of microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 64bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are using a SQL Server 2014 64 bit cluster in Windows server 2012 R2. We have huge amount of MS Access `.mdb` files coming from distributed areas. We use `OpenRowSet` for loading data from Access `.mdb` to SQL Server.

Until we upgraded to 64bit server it was working fine. After migration to 64bit SQL Server we found that Jet.4.0 has no 64bit version so we switched to Ace.12.0 64bit. After upgrading to Ace.12.0 64bit performance has been degraded. Test result is weird.

- SQL 2008R2 64 bit-7sec to 10min
- SQL 2008R2 32 bit-7sec
- SQL 2014 64 bit cluster-7sec-10min

We cannot take initiatives to test in SQL Server 2014 in 32 bit mode.

Tested on the same server on same query. I found that after restart either Server or SQL Server SQL 2014 64bit and 2008R2 32bit/64bit take 7 seconds to execute and it is gradually increased for 64bit as time elapsed. Execution time is not stable on 64bit SQL server but 32 bit SQL server takes fixed 7seconds to executes the query anytime. Ace.12.0 and Jet.4.0 takes the same time in 32bit mode but Ace.12.0 is not stable in 64bit mode.

We use 16core processor with 128GB RAM, 2Node with SAN switch. All network switches are gigabyte switch. 9tb usable storage.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you connect to the Access database as a linked server?

Comment: I have created linked server to Access file and get no change in performance.

Comment: Using sp_Who_Is_Active, take a look at the locking while the data is being loaded, just to confirm that the issue is on the read side (and not the write side - I assume you are loading this into a table?)

Comment: Try upgrading `.mdb` files to `.accdb` files in transition to 64-bit. These types might better align to ACE 12.0 engine.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I have done that also. .accdb also takes the same time. No change between .mdb and .accdb.